# An elementary problem about the meaning of preserving the complex structure.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm a beginner in complex geometry and I want to ask a question about the definition which I did not find explicit formula.

What's the meaning of **'a connection preserve the complex structure'**?
$$
\nabla J=0.
$$
Does it mean that for local coordinate $\left(U ; x^i, y^i\right)$, for any two $v_1$ and $v_2$ in {$x^i, y^i $}, $$
\nabla_{v_i} J(v_j)=0.
$$

Comment: Go back to Riemannian geometry. What does it mean to say that $\nabla g = 0$?